# Высота div растягивалась по содержимому контента тега p

Tags: html, css, html5, frontend, scss

У меня есть блок div с фоновым изображением, внутри него находится тег p с текстом.  Для того, чтобы картинка-фон отображалась полностью я поставила height:100%. Но тогда если я изменяю масштаб странички, содержимое контента p, выходит за рамки блока. Как можно исправить ситуацию: 
Пример:
HTML:

```
<div class="headerPage">
    <p class="headerPage__description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>

Scss:
.headerPage{
    background: url("../images/leave.jpg") top center;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;

    .headerPage__description{
        position: relative;
        top:200px;
        left:25%;
        font-size: 2em;
        color:white;
        font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
        max-width: 700px;
    }


}
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае нужно использовать «padding». См. пример:

```css
.headerPage-description {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #FFEB3B;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
.headerPage {
    background: url(http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2016-12/1481274662_ducktalesserie.jpg) top center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerPage">
    <p class="headerPage-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
```

Ещё: для эстетики можете переписать css:

```
max-width: 700px;
min-width: 100px;
/* width: 100%; */
```

Пример 2:

```css
.headerPage-description {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #FFEB3B;
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.headerPage {
    background: url(http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2016-12/1481274662_ducktalesserie.jpg) top center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerPage">
    <p class="headerPage-description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
```

Если будут вопросы, обращайтесь. Рад помочь.